# Getting data from postgis with hibernate is returning an hash instead of the rows

Tags: postgis, java, hibernate-spatial

Is the first time that i use spring and hibernate starting from the basics,

i need to get geometries from a postgis table populated with Qgis.

I generate a persistence mapping of the table with jpaData model,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comuni_2015", schema = "public", catalog = "springgis")
public class Geomcomuni {

private int id;
private Integer codReg;
private Integer codCm;
private Integer codPro;
private Integer proCom;
private String comune;
private String nomeTed;
private Integer flagCm;
private Double shapeLeng;
private Double shapeArea;
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private MultiPolygon geom;


@Id
@Column(name = "id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}



@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
@Column(name = "geom")
public MultiPolygon getGeom() {
    return geom;
}
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
public void setGeom(MultiPolygon geom) {
    this.geom = geom;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "cod_reg")
public Integer getCodReg() {
    return codReg;
}

public void setCodReg(Integer codReg) {
    this.codReg = codReg;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "cod_cm")
public Integer getCodCm() {
    return codCm;
}

public void setCodCm(Integer codCm) {
    this.codCm = codCm;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "cod_pro")
public Integer getCodPro() {
    return codPro;
}

public void setCodPro(Integer codPro) {
    this.codPro = codPro;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "pro_com")
public Integer getProCom() {
    return proCom;
}

public void setProCom(Integer proCom) {
    this.proCom = proCom;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "comune")
public String getComune() {
    return comune;
}

public void setComune(String comune) {
    this.comune = comune;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "nome_ted")
public String getNomeTed() {
    return nomeTed;
}

public void setNomeTed(String nomeTed) {
    this.nomeTed = nomeTed;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "flag_cm")
public Integer getFlagCm() {
    return flagCm;
}

public void setFlagCm(Integer flagCm) {
    this.flagCm = flagCm;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "shape_leng")
public Double getShapeLeng() {
    return shapeLeng;
}

public void setShapeLeng(Double shapeLeng) {
    this.shapeLeng = shapeLeng;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "shape_area")
public Double getShapeArea() {
    return shapeArea;
}

public void setShapeArea(Double shapeArea) {
    this.shapeArea = shapeArea;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Geomcomuni that = (Geomcomuni) o;

    if (id != that.id) return false;
    if (geom != null ? !geom.equals(that.geom) : that.geom != null) return false;
    if (codReg != null ? !codReg.equals(that.codReg) : that.codReg != null) return false;
    if (codCm != null ? !codCm.equals(that.codCm) : that.codCm != null) return false;
    if (codPro != null ? !codPro.equals(that.codPro) : that.codPro != null) return false;
    if (proCom != null ? !proCom.equals(that.proCom) : that.proCom != null) return false;
    if (comune != null ? !comune.equals(that.comune) : that.comune != null) return false;
    if (nomeTed != null ? !nomeTed.equals(that.nomeTed) : that.nomeTed != null) return false;
    if (flagCm != null ? !flagCm.equals(that.flagCm) : that.flagCm != null) return false;
    if (shapeLeng != null ? !shapeLeng.equals(that.shapeLeng) : that.shapeLeng != null) return false;
    if (shapeArea != null ? !shapeArea.equals(that.shapeArea) : that.shapeArea != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id;
    result = 31 * result + (geom != null ? geom.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (codReg != null ? codReg.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (codCm != null ? codCm.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (codPro != null ? codPro.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (proCom != null ? proCom.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (comune != null ? comune.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (nomeTed != null ? nomeTed.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (flagCm != null ? flagCm.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (shapeLeng != null ? shapeLeng.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (shapeArea != null ? shapeArea.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
}
```

a simple DAO class

```
@Repository
public interface GeomcomuniDao extends CrudRepository<Geomcomuni, Long> {

    Geomcomuni findById(int id);
}
```

and below the App starter

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "applicationContext.xml");

    GeomcomuniDao geomcomuniDao = context.getBean(GeomcomuniDao.class);
    System.out.println("Get second geometry: " + geomcomuniDao.findById(2));
    }
}
```

These are the last lines of the output

> INFO: HHH000261: Table found: public.comuni_2015 mag 01, 2016 1:16:43
>   PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  INFO: HHH000037:
>   Columns: [flag_cm, shape_area, pro_com, comune, cod_pro, id, cod_cm,
>   geom, nome_ted, cod_reg, shape_leng]
>
> **Get second geometry: com.devcrumb.model.Geomcomuni@8ed21ebb**
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

As you can see it returns me a strange alphanumeric string, how can i get a string format of the row for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply print a class. If you want to do so, you have to add a toString() method to it.

See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555771/why-is-the-tostring-method-being-called-when-i-print-an-object or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001664/how-to-create-a-println-print-method-for-a-custom-class or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Comment: Thank you very much, in this case i Opted for calling directly a get method defined in the Entity to get only a field of the row,  for example "geomcomuniDao.findById(2).getGeom()"